# Does a fixed sized array in a struct need to be explicitly destroyed in a C++ destructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Given a contrived example struct like this:

```
static const int ARRAY_SIZE = 64;

struct some_struct
{
    int buffer_size;
    char buffer[ARRAY_SIZE] { 0 };

    some_struct(char* str, int str_len) :
        buffer_size(ARRAY_SIZE)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str_len; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = str[i];
        }
    }
};
```

Does the struct need an explicit destructor to free the array's memory? 
I intend to use the struct on the stack and the heap i.e.

```
// Stack
//
char myStr1[] = "string1";
some_struct myStackStruct(myStr1, 6);

...

// Heap
//
char myStr2[] = "string2";
some_struct* myHeapStruct = new some_struct(myStr2, 6);

...

delete myHeapStruct;
```

Do fixed sized arrays in a struct like this need to be explicitly destroyed in a destructor?

Comment: No. Only `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: you also don't need to mention it in the constructor's member initializer list

Comment: Use std::string, not char arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the struct need an explicit destructor to free the array's
>   memory? I intend to use the struct on the stack and the heap i.e.

You did not write any code that specifies any memory allocation from the heap in your struct declaration. Therefore, the array declaration does not require an explicit dtor to free the memory.

> Do fixed sized arrays in a struct like this need to be explicitly
>   destroyed in a destructor?

A simple rule of thumb is `new` and `delete` come in pairs. There should always be one `delete` for every `new`. In your declaration of your struct you have no calls to `new`, so you do not need to explicitly destroy it in a dtor.

The following line however, puts an instance of the struct on the heap (since you are using `new`). So in *this* situation you need to use `delete` to free the memory allocated.

```
some_struct* myHeapStruct = new some_struct(myStr2, 6);
```

Comment: Another rule of thumb is that you can only delete a pointer. An array is not a pointer.

Comment: "You did not write any code that specifies any memory allocation from the heap." Is this not heap memory? some_struct* myHeapStruct = new some_struct(myStr2, 6);

Comment: @ChrisMcJava: That is an allocation from the heap. However, I was referring to your struct declaration, I've edited my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

No, fixed size array members do not need to be explicitly destroyed.

The array is part your struct's data, so it will be destroyed when you destroy the struct.

You can see this using `sizeof()`:

```
struct some_struct
{
    char[64] data;
};

static_assert(sizeof(some_struct) == 64 * sizeof(char));
```

In general, every destruction matches a creation; you explicitly destroy something only if you explicitly created it. If you declare a `some_struct` instance on the stack, the data will be unloaded when the `some_struct` goes out of scope. If you allocate a `some_struct` with `new()` or `malloc()`, the data will be in a single block, unloaded when you `delete()` or `free()` the `some_struct` instance.

Answer (score 0):

If your class internally uses `new` then you must define the destructor to use `delete` appropriately: also if you define the class's destructor you should also define the class's copy constructor & overloaded `operator=()` refer to the Rule of 3,4 or 5.

If your class does not internally use `new` then no.

If you are using new on the class itself in some other piece of code, then you would have to delete that class where needed.